# How to install Ubuntu on usb drive (not live simulation)

Tags: installation, usb, disk

I want to install Ubuntu on my usb disk. But not as a live CD.
I want to connect to a PC, and boot my ubuntu as on a normal PC. So that I can make changes and install new programs.
With a live cd is this not possible.

All the tools that I saw here were tools to create a live usb disk. But this is not really what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You will need two media at this process.
One which was prepared as installation media.
Second media for installing in it.

1. Create a live (installation) media (usb/cd).
2. Boot the computer with the installation media with the Install option
3. While it is being prepared, plugin your USB where your real OS will be installed.
4. Follow the steps and select Something Else at the right step.
5. Choose your OS USB disk to install. (Possibly, sdc)
6. Click on it and select / for mount point and "Format it"
7. Also be carefull to choose your OS USB to install GRUB where it asks "Where to grub install?"
8. It will be installed to your USB.